# Accessing child scope in watch

Tags: angularjs

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2XpEudto3rVbksgsSYjs?p=preview) I have two nested directives, each with a checkbox. My objective is to change the parent checkbox whenever the user clicks on the child checkbox. I need to use watch (no messages), but I cannot access the child scope. Any ideas?

Javascript

```
angular.module('app', []);


angular.module('app')
    .directive('directive1', function() 

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.scope = true;

    directive.template = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb1"> Top directive <br/><directive2></directive2> ';

    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.$watch(function () {'cb2' }, 
              function (newValue, oldValue) {
                  scope.cb1 = newValue;
       });


    };

    return directive;

});


angular.module('app')
    .directive('directive2', function() {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.scope = true;

    directive.template = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb2">  Bottom directive ';

    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    };

        return directive;

});
```

Comment: try to use the watcher for child outside of the parent directive. use it in the controller level and see what happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prototypical inheritance to work correctly, the `ng-model` directive needs to have a value with a "dot".

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="d1.cb2">
```

Then the parent directive needs to create the `d1` object and watch `d1.cb2`.

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('directive1', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.scope = true;
    directive.template = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb1"> Top directive <br/><directive2></directive2> ';

    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.d1 = {};
      scope.$watch('d1.cb2', 
                    function (newValue, oldValue) {
                       scope.cb1 = newValue;  
                    }
      );
    };

    return directive;

});
```

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try **2-way data binding** (i.e., form elements, ng-model) **to a primitive** (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.

For more information about prototypical inheritance, see [AngularJS Wiki -- The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/ChuI23AGvkEJt9f6R67S?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

You can set a function in the parent that will make the checkbox checked.

And in the child directive [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate) the parent and call its function.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
  element[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    ctrl.checkSelected();
  })
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zM3Gip5DLbmtPOuxrhif?p=preview

I took the liberty to refactor your code a little.